# Is there a simple way to move all terms with $x$ or $y$ in the LHS and all others in the RHS of an equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I did the following:

> [image]

In the last equations, is there a simple way to move all terms with $x$ or $y$ in the LHS and all others in the RHS?

Comment: `is there a simple way to move all terms with x or y in the LHS and all others in the RHS?` having hard time parsing this. Do you mean you want everything moved to one side then?   i.e.   `all= 0`  instead of `stuff_1 = stuff_2` ?

Comment: @Nasser Sorry, my english is terrible. I mean I want an expression in the form: something$x$ + something$y$ $=$ everything not x nor y.

Answer (score 6):

> I mean I want an expression in the form: somethingx + somethingy =
>   everything not x nor y.

may be not the simplest way.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eq = -a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 == -r + r2;
lhs = eq /. (lhs_ == rhs_) -> lhs;
rhs = eq /. (lhs_ == rhs_) -> rhs;
eq = lhs - rhs;
xTerms = Cases[List @@ eq, x^any0_.*any_. :> x^any0*any];
yTerms = Cases[List @@ eq, y^any0_.*any_. :> y^any0*any];
otherTerms = eq - (Plus @@ xTerms + Plus @@ yTerms);
eq =  Plus @@ xTerms + Plus @@ yTerms == otherTerms
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For

```
eq = x^3 + 2 Sqrt[y] + a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x^2 + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 == -r + r2;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc..

Bug reports are always welcome and will be processed in the order they are recived.

Answer (score 6):

1. `Expand` (if necessary)
2. `SubtractSides`
3. `ReplaceAll` `x` and `y` with `0` on the lhs to get terms free of `x` or `y`
4. `SubtractSides` again using the expression obtained in previous step as the second argument.

The function `reOrg` combines the four steps:

```
ClearAll[reOrg]
reOrg = Module[{ss = SubtractSides[ Expand @ #]}, 
    SubtractSides[ss, ReplaceAll[Alternatives @@ #2 -> 0] @ ss[[1]]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
reOrg[-a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 == -r + r2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
>  2 a x - 2 a2 x + 2 b y - 2 b2 y == a^2 - a2^2 + b^2 - b2^2 - r + r2
> ```

Move terms with `a` or `b` to the left:

```
reOrg[-a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 == -r + r2, {a, b}]
```

> ```
>  -a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y == -a2^2 - b2^2 - r + r2 + 2 a2 x + 2 b2 y
> ```

With Nasser's second example:

```
reOrg[x^3 + 2 Sqrt[y] + a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x^2 + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 
  == -r + r2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
>  -2 a2 x + 2 a x^2 + x^3 + 2 Sqrt[y] + 2 b y - 2 b2 y ==
>    -a^2 - a2^2 + b^2 - b2^2 - r + r2
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`` Internal`DependsOnQ[expr, {x, y,...}] `` is a nice, if undocumented, tool that helps with this kind of thing.

```
sep[a_ == b_, vars_] := With[{
    depends = GroupBy[
      List @@ (a - b),
      Internal`DependsOnQ[#, vars] &,
      Total]},
   depends[True] == -depends[False]
   ];
```

Example:

```
sep[
 -a^2 - b^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y - 2 x a2 + a2^2 - 2 y b2 + b2^2 == -r + r2,
 {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   2 a x - 2 a2 x + 2 b y - 2 b2 y == 
>    a^2 - a2^2 + b^2 - b2^2 - r + r2
> *)
> ```

By design, I let the user decide how much to `Expand` the equation in `sep[eqn, vars]`.